# Google wallet order details API

Tags: android-pay

I'm wondering if there is any API available for getting order details from Google Wallet. Details are available in Walelt Merchant Center UI - under *Orders* and also it can be downlaoded as a report for given timeframe.
However, I wasn't able to find any API which can be used for similar purposes. Is it available?

Comment: Which product Instant Buy?  Google Play?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it doesn't look like order details are explicitly available via the Google Wallet API. [From the FAQ](https://developers.google.com/wallet/digital/faq#faq-gen-01):

> **What is the Google Wallet for Digital Goods API?**
>
> It's a way to let customers make simple payments without leaving your web app.

Also, the API documentation references the Merchant Center in [How-to Guides > Managing Orders](https://developers.google.com/wallet/digital/docs/orders) and provides no way of obtaining this data via the API.

> Google Wallet for Digital Goods orders are charged automatically and
>   you can view processed orders using the [Merchant Center](https://wallet.google.com/merchant), an online
>   interface that allows you to manage orders placed through the Google
>   Wallet for Digital Goods API.
>
> Through the Merchant Center you can:
>
> - Cancel orders
> - Refund orders
> - Review your payout information
> - Generate and download reports

The Google Wallet API does state:

> **Note**: If you're developing an Android app, you should instead use Google Play In-app billing.

It's possible the the [In-app Billing API](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html) ([`getPurchases()` method?](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html#getPurchases)) may have more available in terms of order details than the Google Wallet API.