# Google Wallet / IAP API

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play

I work on a mobile game company. I need to make a tool for client support.
Sometimes user have issue with IAP and give us their transaction id like GPA.1234-5678-9012-34567 
I don't find any API to query Google Wallet and check if this transaction id exists and at which in-app-products it match.
For now, I log in the Google Wallet Website and search for it ... but it's not efficient.

Have you any idea?

Answer (score 0):

From inside the app, you can send `orderId`, `purchaseToken` and `productId` that you get in [`INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA`](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html) to your backend server. You can then query for `orderId` on your server using an API and find associated `purchaseToken` and `productId`.

Using `purchaseToken` and `productId`, you can retrieve purchase info from [Google Play Developer API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/products/get)

Comment: Yes but it's not inside the app. it's, if the IAP don't work and player contact the game support.

Comment: Don't think Google Wallet provides an API to let you know associated in app product details. Your client will somehow need to store orderId, purchaseToken and productId at the time of purchase to a server. I guess in app purchase is done from inside the app.

Comment: Yes I know that ... but sometimes bug appears (disconnect for example) and player contact us with only their transaction id.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26343611/google-wallet-order-details-api seems like not possible unless you store associated purchaseToken on a server

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have the same conclusion. I'll try to work with this report: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870#export